# Doxygen , extension mapping and parsing c.ftl and other files

Tags: doxygen

I auto generate a lot of code and would also like to pull the documentation from the header and c files.  The problem I have is I store all of my source code in *.ftl files that I then convert to the C files when the user needs them.  So I have lots of *.c.ftl files, *.h.ftl files, *.s.ftl files, *.asm.ftl files etc...  But going through the documentation and testing out different options, it appears that doxygen only uses the file type following the last "dot".  Is there a way I could set "c.ftl"=C and "h/ftl"=H for the parsing?  When I tried setting c.ftl=C in extension mapping, it does not work.

Comment: When I get it right you want to use the generated `.c.tfl` and `.h.tfl` files to be processed by doxygen. What will happen with the `.s,ftl` (what kind of file is this?), `.asm.tfl`?. Do you generated the `.c.tfl` files on the same directory as where the original `.tfl` files are? When the `.s` and `.asm` can be ignored it might be that  `EXTENSION_MAPPING= tfl=C` can work when you also set the the `FILE_PATTERNS = *.c.ftl *,h,ftl"`. Another solution might be to use instead of `.c.tfl` the extension `c_tfl` or `.tfl.c`. Looks like `EXCLUDE_PATTERNS=*.s.tfl" works as well

Comment: In looking at similar projects that do this, one method uses script to first call freemarker or jinja2 or other template language to generate a version of the *.c and *.h filescontaining all of the header/prototype information.  Then point doxygen at that directory and use that version of the files for the help file.  Since the header and comments will be the same, the doxygen output will contain all of the data I need.